# Not able to view JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have below code in `app.js`.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3001;
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.send("success");
});
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema=new Schema({
 created_at: String,
 id: Number
  });

 const Products = mongoose.model("myc",productSchema);
 app.get('/',function(req,res){
 Products.find({},function(err,products){
  res.json(products)
  });
  })

 // module.exports = app;
```

I have created mongodb database `mydb` and `myc` as collection which contents the document.

When i type localhost:3000, I dont see the JSON data stored in Mongodb its shows only blank page. Please help

Comment: The connection is still awaiting promise or event resolution and not actually connected yet. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: I suggest you add some console logging so you can check exactly which lines are getting hit. I don't know what the code for `index` does in `app.use('/', index);` but that may be sending the response. If that doesn't break it then your 404 generator will as you've currently got that registered before your `app.get('/', ...`. The middleware/routes will be called in the order they are registered.

Comment: I dont have any code in Index.jade.. Not sure how to resolve it I am new to nodejs:(

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3001;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema=new Schema({
created_at: String,
id: Number
});

const Products = mongoose.model("myc",productSchema);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
Products.find({},function(err,products){
if(!err){
res.json(products)
}
else{
res.send(err)
}
});
})
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: added it no luck.. I see this error in command prompt.GET /favicon.ico 404

Comment: I have to display data present in mongodb, so used mongoose to create a rest api so that if i hit link localhost:3000 need to get data in DB as JSON on browser

Comment: @PratheeshM I have modified according to my schema but no Json printed. Updated the code above.Thanks

Comment: Products.find({}
,function(err,products){
if(!err){res.json(products)}
else{
res.send(err);
}
  });
  })

Comment: Only success is printed.No json data

Comment: remove `module.exports = app;`

Comment: also ensure that your mongodb is running and there are db and collection as you specified

Comment: how many files do you have? where are you using that exported object

Comment: please remove port from the mongo url

Comment: Now the browser keeps on loading :(